# $f(x) = 2x^2 + 4x+3$, Express in Vertex Form: Give the Vertex and $y-$ and $x-$ intercepts

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't find the $x$ intercepts!
My vertex form is $2(x+1)^2 +1$

My $y-$intercept is $3$
and my vertex is $(-1,1)$

However, I am stuck trying to find the $x$ intercepts. 
I have $-\frac{1}{2} = (x+1)^2$

However, one can't square a negative number, well at least not at my level of math. Can some one show me how to solve the is problem using vertex form?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ does not have $x\rm - intercept $. This means that the parabola lies above the $x-axis$, geometrically. Algebraically, it is easy to observe that $f(x) = 2 (x + 1 )^2 + 1 > 0 $ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$. This follows from the trivial inequality : $x^2 \geq 0 $ for all $x$ and the fact that $1 > 0 $. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Did not notice that.

Comment: you are welcome.